# Autohotkey | RegExMatch() . How can I do this thing?

Tags: autohotkey

I got a value from website and want to retrieve only one value. Tried over amd over, it is too difficult for me now.

I only need 'balance' from the second.

```
([{'currency': 'KRW', 'balance': '10134.93', 'locked': '0.0', 'avg_krw_buy_price': '0', 'modified': False}, {'currency': 'XRP', 'balance': '20.0', 'locked': '0.0', 'avg_krw_buy_price': '508.66', 'modified': False}], {'group': 'default', 'min': 1799, 'sec': 29})
```

I read the manual and referred to the similar(almost identical), couldn't do it myself. Would appreciate your help.

Comment: RegExMatch(Clipboard, "balance': '(.*?)\.", Balances). I have no idea why it doesn't let me parse properly. I put the exact characters in it expecially <   ': '    >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code `RegExMatch(Clipboard, "balance': '(.*?)\.", Balances).` works correctly, perhaps you're not reading the clipboard or the output correctly? The RegExMatch function in AutoHotkey returns the matched result in an output variable defined on the third parameter.

```
haystack_str:= "([{'currency': 'KRW', 'balance': '10134.93', 'locked': '0.0', 'avg_krw_buy_price': '0', 'modified': False}, {'currency': 'XRP', 'balance': '20.0', 'locked': '0.0', 'avg_krw_buy_price': '508.66', 'modified': False}], {'group': 'default', 'min': 1799, 'sec': 29})"
RegExMatch(haystack_str, "balance': '(.*?)\.", Balances)
msgbox % Balances
```

Comment: Cheers! How can I choose this as a answer? So stressed out, I ended up on changing it to StringLeft , etc. What a shame..